# How did Groot manage to raise the axe of Thor when even Hulk failed?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, the-avengers

In *Avengers* Hulk tried to raise Thor's hammer and failed miserably. In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Groot raises Thor's new axe and holds it for a few seconds! Is the axe made of some other light material, or is Groot stronger than Hulk?

[image: Hulk]
[image: Groot]

Comment: Lifting the hammer is not a test of strength. It has a King Arthur, sword in the stone, element to it... *worthiness.*

Comment: ...also simply **not a hammer**... it's an **axe**.

Comment: @Paulie_D But Thor calls it a hammer.

Comment: Anything's a hammer if you hit a nail hard enough with it.

Comment: Thor always had the "hammer" as a weapon , so he dreamt of having a new hammer instead of as a replacement, so he uses the term hammer instead of a general weapon.This turns out to be an axe (a combo of both) though !!

Comment: It looks like a splitting maul to me.

Comment: Even the images in the question itself are 2 *completely* separate weapons... Why do you think they should be compared equally??

Comment: Related: [Does Stormbreaker have the same worthiness specifications as Mjolnir?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186773/21267)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb 1. Mjolnir was made at the same place as Stormbreaker, what means it would be no different material. 2. Thor uses it the same as the previous axe(hammer), so that means that they are different only by one side.

Comment: @VerNick - That comparison is absolutely *not* correct or fair. That's like saying that a Smith & Wesson rifle is the same as one of their revolvers because they're made in the same factory and out of the same metal (disclaimer: I don't know if they *actually* make these at the same factory or of the exact same metal... but you get my point).

Comment: Please stop making nonsense edits to your question!

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The hammer Mjolnir, Thor's previous weapon, had an enchantment placed upon it by Odin so that it could only be wielded by those who were "worthy" of doing so. Hulk and the other Avengers couldn't pick it up not because they lacked the physical strength, but because for reasons we're not privy to, Mjolnir deemed them unworthy 
 -- with the exceptions of Vision and

> Captain America, as shown in *Endgame*.

The axe Stormbreaker never had that enchantment placed upon it, something [confirmed by the Russo brothers themselves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192312/76048). Therefore, all that's required to lift it is physical strength.

Comment: _Mjolnir deemed them unworthy._ Except Cap.  Kind of.

Comment: @user1717828 Cap probably decided himself not to lift it after seeing that he could

Comment: @user1717828 Looks like I miss something. did captain lift it?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza IIRC, Captain America manages to move it *slightly*. It's unclear whether that's as far as he could move it, or whether he could have picked it up completely but chose not to.

Comment: @F1Krazy I guess that was in original Avengers? Dont recall that part

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's in Age of Ultron. Most of the Avengers go through a party scene that ends up some of them trying to lift Mjolnir - then Ultron shows up in the flesh (not yet).

Comment: @user1717828, and [Mr. Rogers](https://www.reddit.com/r/wholesomememes/comments/9oj10k/what_it_would_be_like_if_thor_visited_mr_rogers/).

Comment: So Groot is stronger than the Hulk?

Comment: @BruceWayne I doubt it.

Comment: @BruceWayne what leads you to think that? Hulk never tried the axe, groot never tried the hammer

Comment: @Aethenosity ohhh, whoops. I confused the two.

Comment: Ok, then one must ask if Thanos will wield Stormbreaker in AV4.

Answer (score 14):

@F1Krazy Perfect, Stormbreaker didn't have any spell(s) bound to it, it was a weapon made out of Uru. However, notice how Thor tells Starlord that **"your bodies will be crushed as your mind collapses into madness"** while referring to his new weapon (turns out to be Stormbreaker).

So now I ask **"if not the guardians, why Groot specifically?"** Well, **Stormbreaker wasn't formed completely** first of all. Secondly we can CLEARLY see teen Groot in pain and feeling the burn when he uses his arm and chops it off to complete the weapon-building.

The axe became the actual Stormbreaker AFTER Thor channeled his lightning through it.

Also, **picking up a weapon for a few seconds** is NOT EQUAL to **wielding it for long durations,** and DEFINITELY NOT EQUAL TO **using it in any battles** like Thor did!!

Providing a ref link as well, here you go !!---> https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-groot-thor-axe-stormbreaker-explained/

Comment: hope this clears up things !

Comment: oh lol, now I noticed , F1's answer is right, I added the exact official statements to make a complete answer.

Comment: _"The axe became the actual Stormbreaker AFTER Thor channelized his lightning through it."_ Your link does not support this claim and in the movie it seems that Stormbreaker actually saves Thor's live. - __Rocket:__ _"I think he [Thor] is dying!"_ __Eitri:__ _"He needs the axe ... where is the handle? Tree, help me find the handle!"_ - Once Groot finishes the axe with his arm, Stormbreaker starts floating and giving off lightning. Thor weakly opens his hand and we see tiny sparks of lightning between his fingers [we don't see him touch Stormbreaker].

Comment: Also, there was nothing special about the weapon until it was whole. That's why Dinklage (spacing on the characters' name) was frantic to find the handle to save Thor; it was just pieces off metal until made whole. So Groot could pick it up in pieces and when it became whole, Groot *became* the handle, and a handle has to be able to lift itself.

Comment: Right now the answer is quite confusingly written, starting like a comment on the other answer, with unnecessary bold and caps lock overused for emphasis. I'd suggest editing it to clean it up.

Comment: So far I'm considering Thor's comment with regard to going crazy as a bluff. He was tough talking with Starlord in that scene and we have no indication yet that Stormbreaker is harmful to other persons than Thor.

Comment: I am not sure that Groot is in pain because it is Stormbreaker. Most likely because he is holding extremely hot metallic pieces.

Comment: @Taladris Agree.

Comment: This answer looks like a comment, trying to reply on F1Krazy's answer. you should remove those sections to make this looks like an independant answer

Comment: @V2Blast +1 for "*a handle has to be able to lift itself*". Completely logical and completely not, at the same time. :)

Comment: @Lawrence: Did you intend to mention Daevin, since he was the one who mentioned that?

Comment: @V2Blast oops, yes! Sorry about that.

Answer (score -3):

Groot is worthy as per Odin's user credentials i.e whom ever be worthy shall weild the power of Thor Vision is also worth in layman's terms no hidden agenda just the will to do good.

Comment: Can you flesh this answer out with more information and/or proof? This seems rather short for this site. I am not saying you are wrong, but maybe look around at other accepted answers to get a better idea of what the site is generally after. Even this comment seems longer than your answer. I do not want dissuade you, I like that you took the tour. You're ahead of most two day members. Please stick around.